# Show images in java located out of the java project

Tags: java, image, imageicon

I have to do a program which shows images located out of the java project. I don't know how to represent them, I can represent images located in the project but not out of them.
These is what I am doing:

```
private String imagedir = "C://";
private String imageFileNames = "mypic.jpg";    
ImageIcon icon;   
icon = createImageIcon(imagedir + imageFileNames);
```

This gives me: `Couldnt find file.`

Comment: What is hidden in `createImageIcon()`  method?

Comment: protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,String description) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);

            return null;
        }

Answer (score 1):

**Don't place images outside the project. What will happen when your project is shipped?**

How will you run the same project on another system?

---

Put all the images in `images` folder that you have in your project in parallel to `src` folder.

```
 F:/>Kiosk
             |
             |___src
             |
             |___lib
             |
             |___koisk
                   |
                   |__main1.java
             |
             |__images
                |
                |__c.jpg
                |__d.jpg
                |__e.jpg
                |__f.jpg
```

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from absolute path
ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"));
```

Comment: I cant locate the images in the workspace because more images will be added long time. The app is going to be used for a university department, so the images folder will be located on a server in the same path for all of them.

Comment: @user3597131 **have you tried my second option?** Read from absolute path.

Comment: @user3597131 What [Class#getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) states. Don't use this method to read from outside the project.